# Determine DataContext of a WPF control at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**How to determine the `DataContext` of a specific control at design time in a `WPF` application?**

`DataContext` might be specifically set in `XAML`, inherited or set somewhere in code and sometimes it is hard to figure out at design time which class the bindings are referring to.

What I usually try to do to find the `DataContext` class is to search the binding name in VS. For example I see the binding is something like

```
ItemSource = {Binding Items}
```

...I will search the text "Items" in order to get to the class but VS sometimes fails to find the searched text (I have several projects in the solution).

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer for this, as it isn't known at design time. A few options at run time are a) set an invalid binding and check your output - it might give you error saying property not found on object <name> b) add something like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}"/>`, but that will only show the class name if there's no DataTemplate associated or c) just the longer way of searching for the View class name to see how it is initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataContext` of `Control` is `ViewModel`. So there are many ways to set `ViewModel` for `DataContext` of `View`,  and if you find your `ViewModel`, but there is no `Items` property in `ViewModel`, then it means that you should add such property to get work binding.

Also, I recommend you to see `Debug->Windows->Output` window where you can see binding info. That is you can know binding errors.

To conclude, I would like to show ways of setting `ViewModel` to `DataContext`:

There are many approaches to set DataContext:

**The first approach.** In view:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

**The second approach.** You should override `OnStartUp()` method of `App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
     protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWindow app = new MainWindow();
            ProductViewModel context = new ProductViewModel();
            app.DataContext = context;
            app.Show();
     }
}
```

**The third approach.** In constructor of Windows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     public MainWindow()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          DataContext=new MainWindowViewModel();
     }
}
```

**The fourth approach.** You can set `DataContext` through `DependencyInjection` by `UnityContainer` or another IoC container. But `DependencyInjection`, `Prism` and `UnityContainer` are other questions and goes from this scope of the question. Just for example:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
{ 
    unityContainer.RegisterType<object, ItemControl>("ModuleAUpper");
    unityContainer.RegisterType<IViewModelItemControl, ViewModelItemControl>();
    unityContainer.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ItemControl>();
}
```

Comment: Debug->Windows->Output is probably workable solution. I know the ways to set DataContext (here it is set by other developers which I just want to figure out the easiest way)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add an approach to StepUp´s listing:

**The design instance:**

Just like you can define a run time data context, you can add a data context that is specifically for the  design time via:

```
    <Usercontrol    x:Class="MyUserControl"  
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MyViewModel}"
                    d:DesignHeight="300"
                    d:DesignWidth="600"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">
    </UserControl>
```

In Visual Studio you can then use IntelliSense for bindable properties and if your view model has an uncomplicated or even parameterfree constructor, it will be created in the Designer and you can test trigger or converters without having to start your application.